# NullPointerException in Processing 2

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception, processing, words

I have some processing code, which i know works. But when i begin rewriting the code into a setup and draw setup(i think its called active), it gives me a "NullPointerException", when running it. Can it be something with the arrays?
hope you can help me :) 
(*and yes i know it is alot of slave code writing, but it was the only way i could figure it out :3 im a newbie to processing and coding in general. also i ruled out some of the slave stuff, so it was only the code i know gave me problems*):

```
    //stating the int's and strings
String[] lines = loadStrings("brown.txt");//the array with the words
String longString = join(lines, " "); //joining the array to a normal string of words
int characters = longString.length(); //used to find the amount of all the letters
String lowercase = longString.toLowerCase();//makes sure all the letters are lowercased

//setting up the letter freqiency finder
char[] c = lowercase.toCharArray(); //used to make a character array
int freq = 0, freq2 = 0, freq3 = 0, freq4 = 0,              //|
freq5 = 0, freq6 = 0, freq7 = 0, freq8 = 0, freq9 = 0,      //|
freq10 = 0, freq11 = 0, freq12 = 0, freq13 = 0,             //|naming and setting all the frequencies
freq14 = 0, freq15 = 0, freq16 = 0, freq17 = 0, freq18 = 0, //|
freq19 = 0, freq20 = 0, freq21 = 0, freq22 = 0, freq23 = 0, //|
freq24 = 0, freq25 = 0, freq26 = 0;                         //|

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
//setting up the letter counters
  for (int i = 0; i< c.length; i++)
  {
    if (c[i]=='a')
      freq++; 
    if (c[i]=='b')
      freq2++; 
    ......... etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do variable manipulation outside of a function in Processing. Before `setup()`, you should *declare* your variables, but you give them values in `setup()`. See [here](http://processing.org/tutorials/data/) (under "Reading and Writing Text Files") for an example of this. Here is what you should do with your code:

```java
String[] lines;
int[] freq;

void setup(){
    size(600,600);
    background(255);
    lines = loadStrings("brown.txt");//the array with the words
    if(lines == null){
      print("error loading strings!");
    }
    String longString = join(lines, " "); //joining the array to a normal string of words
    int characters = longString.length(); //used to find the amount of all the letters
    String lowercase = longString.toLowerCase();//makes sure all the letters are lowercased

    //setting up the letter frequency finder
    char[] c = lowercase.toCharArray(); //used to make a character array
    freq = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
      //chars are really just numbers and a-z is consecutive, so 'a' - 'a' = 0, 'b' - 'a' = 1, 'c' - 'a' = 2...
      // note that you can also check to see if a character is between a-z by doing if(chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z'){}
      freq[c[i] - 'a']++;
    }
}
void draw() {}
```

Comment: Cheers. Side note: I moved all the code to the `setup()` function because there's no need to run it 60 times per second, which is what `draw()` does-- once is enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this `String[] lines = new String[]{};` then `lines = loadStrings("brown.txt");` if the problem persists the issue is certainly in your loadString Method

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I tried it setting it up like this now:
String[] lines = new String[]{}; and next line 
lines = loadStrings("brown.txt");

but it soesnt work :)

Comment: One of the must important rule in OOP. Every time you use a reference first check if it's not null, it will save you a lot of time!!! :)

Comment: And sorry for asking, but how do i check if if its a null or not? :)

Comment: I don't exactly what it is you do in your loadString and in your join method but try to add a if (myobject != null) everyWhere you think it's necessary to check, then debug your code and you'll have your answer :)

Comment: but i cannot add an if statement in the top part, i can only do that in draw can't i? :)

Comment: It's complicated to say as i don't exactly know what your functions are doing. Take a few minutes and debug your code step by step. You'll find the issue. Generally NullReferenceException are not to complicated to solve of course if you have access to the code of all your functions :)

Comment: thanks for all your help, i think im going to try to make some classes instead :)